# Avoid repeated imports in Java: Inherit imports?

Tags: java, inheritance, import, enums

Is there a way to "inherit" imports?

**Example:**

Common enum:

```
public enum Constant{ ONE, TWO, THREE }
```

Base class using this enum:

```
public class Base {
    protected void register(Constant c, String t) {
      ...
    }
}
```

Sub class needing an import to use the enum constants convenient (without enum name):

```
import static Constant.*; // want to avoid this line!  
public Sub extends Base {
    public Sub() {
        register(TWO, "blabla"); // without import: Constant.TWO
    }
}
```

and another class with same import ...

```
import static Constant.*; // want to avoid this line!
public AnotherSub extends Base {
    ...
}
```

I could use classic static final constants but maybe there is a way to use a common enum with the same convenience.

Comment: If you use an IDE (say Eclipse) then imports will be automatically added when you use the class.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`import`s are just an aid to the compiler to find classes. They are active for a single source file and have no relation whatsoever to Java's OOP mechanisms.

So, no, you cannot “inherit” `import`s

Answer (score 4):

If you're using Eclipse, use "Organize Imports" (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>) to let the IDE do the imports for you (or use code completion (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>)

Comment: Even better, set this up as a "Save Action" so Eclipse will organize them every time you save the file. This and formatting on Save helps save any brain cycles thinking about such things :)

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't inherit an import.  If you want to reference a type within a class file without using the fully-qualified name, you have to import it explicitly.

But in your example it would be easy enough to say

```
public Sub extends Base {
    public Sub() {
        register(Constant.TWO, "blabla"); // without import: Constant.TWO
    }
}
```