# Why should the Java compiler not support inheritance of imports?

Tags: java, inheritance, import, compilation

In Java, imports are related to an (outer) class, as every (outer) class is supposed to be coded in a separate file. Thus, one could claim that the `import ...;` directives before a class definition are associated with the class (somewhat like annotations are).

Now, if one could inherit a parent class' imports, that would greatly reduce the clutter of source files. Why should this not be possible? i.e. why should the Java compiler not consider also the imports of base classes?

Notes:

- There's probably more than one answer.
- I know this is not much of an issue if you let eclipse organize your imports, no need to mention that. This is about the 'why', not the 'how' (a-la-[this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2042050/1593077)).

Comment: You can declare more than one class in one file. Imports are related to the file, not a class.

Comment: what if a parent class imports `java.lang.annotation.Annotation` and in a subclass you want to use `java.text.Annotation`. This would be complicated if imports were inherited.

Comment: I let my IDE manage all the imports and fold them away so I don't even see them. I find I don't have to think about them very often.

Comment: Imports are syntactic sugar, nothing more.  You could write any Java program without ever using an import statement if you really wanted to.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Firstly, it is important to note that not every class must be coded in a separate file - but rather that every *public, top level* class must be. And no, imports are not really associated with any class - they are just statements used to include certain external classes / packages within a file so that they can be used. In fact, you never need to actually import anything, you can always use the full name, i.e.:

```
java.util.List<String> list = new java.util.ArrayList<String>();
```

Imports are there for convenience (and only for the compiler - they are lost after the class is compiled), to save you from having to write all that out and instead only make you write `List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>` (after you make the relevant imports from `java.util`). Consequently, there is no reason why subclasses should 'inherit' imports.

Comment: +1 every public, top level class must be in it's own file. public nested classes can share a file.

Comment: +1 and I think it's important to explicitly state that the imports are there for the compiler only (or for ease of readability to avoid fully qualified names -- whichever reason you prefer). They are lost after the class is compiled.

Comment: Thanks, made those clarifications.

Comment: Your conclusion is not a consequence of your premise. The fact that imports are a tool of convenience is not a reason for them not to be 'inherited', at least in the context of compilation. The compiler can be aware of the parent class' imports even if after compilation is done all of this information is discarded.

Comment: @einpoklum It is implied that imports are not related to any particular class, which is why it makes no sense for them to be inherited in any way - since they are not associated with any superclass.

Comment: @A.R.S.: So, they can be made related to a class. The question is why not.

Comment: @einpoklum Well because that's how the language is designed. As I said, imports exist for convenience and they add no functionality to any actual class. As another comment mentioned, they are lost after the class is compiled.

Comment: In other words, the statement *"`import ...;` directives before a class definition are associated with the class (somewhat like annotations are)."* is not true, as these imports are lost after compilation.

Answer (score 2):

Imports are syntactic sugar, nothing more.  You could write any Java program without ever using an import statement if you really wanted to.  For example, the following class compiles all by itself:

```
class Foo {
  java.util.List<String> list = new java.util.ArrayList<String>();
}
```

Additionally, inheriting imports makes it *much, much* harder to remove an import from a class.  For example, if `Bar.java` inherits from `Foo.java`, you might not be able to remove an import from `Foo` without adding it to `Bar`.  Forcing imports to be explicit makes it significantly easier to change a single file without worrying about the effects on other files, which is pretty much a fundamental principle of Java and object-oriented programming generally.

(This last point is related to issues that were [a significant factor in the design of Go](http://talks.golang.org/2012/splash.article#TOC_5.), which was specifically attempting to avoid the problems with C and C++ in this area.)

Comment: So, you're saying that a removal of the import from Foo would require a re-compilation of Bar which might fail. But, why is that a problem? Let is fail, and let the author of Bar make the import itself. It's what s/he needs to do today anyways, right?

Comment: In the scenario you propose, Foo imports Baz, and Bar imports Foo but also needs Baz.  If Foo wants to delete the Baz import, then Bar suddenly no longer gets Baz from Foo, and has to be rewritten, not just recompiled.  That's the problem.

Comment: How is it a problem? Suppose Bar inherits a method from Foo, and the moethod is removed from Foo. That would also require a rewrite. Same thing with inheritance of Baz by Foo. Once you associate imports with a class this becomes reasonable. IMHO.

Comment: There's a distinction between changing the _implementation_ of Foo and changing the _API_ of Foo.  Java makes it easy to change the implementation of Foo without modifying the users of Foo, which your proposal would make hard. No language makes it easy to change the API of Foo without changing the users of Foo.

Answer (score 1):

Having each file explicitly specify its imports improves readability. Imagine opening a file and not being able to see the dependencies at a glance, because the imports are inherited from another file.

Comment: I don't need to imagine it, I have it in real life: In most other languages you 'import' things which themselves 'import' other things, e.g. include files in C and C++.

Comment: ... and having 70 imports is not really that much of a readability win (unless you're the compiler of course).