# Java - Using imported methods from superclass

Tags: java, inheritance, extends

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why should the Java compiler not support inheritance of imports?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14074874/why-should-the-java-compiler-not-support-inheritance-of-imports)

Is it possible for me to do the following:
Say I have a class `A` which extends class `B`. `B` has imported class `C` which has it's own methods that `B` uses. Can `A` use those same methods from `C` without importing `C` directly, since `A` extends `B`?

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to import the same classes in class A?  Sounds like you're up to something fishy...

Comment: This was just one of those "what if..." questions. I was only wondering if Java made that possible.

Comment: Not to discourage you from asking questions but sometimes its best to go try if its possible first :)... I used to have a professor that said "human intervention" should be a last resort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

But if you had said:

*Say I have a class A which extends class B. B has <strike>imported</strike> **extended** class C which has it's own methods that B uses. Can A use those same methods from C without importing C directly, since A extends B*.

Then A could use C's `protected` and `public` methods (and friendly methods if its in the same package) without importing C.

Comment: Right. I was just wondering this since B can use C's methods. Anyways, I received lots of wonderful responses, so thank you! :)

Comment: Yes I only clarified in case thats what you meant and for future people who land on this question.

Answer (score 5):

The `imports` keyword is a syntactic construct; it has nothing to do with classes declared in that file.

When you use a class, the compiler has no way of knowing what classes or packages its source code imported.

Answer (score 3):

No. Imports are local to the class.

You would have to either:

- import C into A
- create a method in B, which A can call, that wraps the call to C

Comment: ok. Even though this is a redundant question, it never hurts to be curious, right? :) Thanks!